# Error when creating a radar chart with chart.js version 4.2.1

Tags: chart.js

Problem with Chart.js version > 4

- With the following scriptversion radar charts are working https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js
- the version 4.2.1 gives an error with radar charts.
  [https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.js">](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.js%22%3E) error in chart.js line 7 (unexpected token "{". ... -->

I don't find a working example for Chartjs > 4.0

```
``
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chart.js Radar Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

<!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script> --> <!-- works -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.js"></script> <!--     doesn't work -->
<!-- error in chart.js line 7 (unespected token "{". ... -->

        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

            new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'radar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Whatever 1',
                        data: [12, 19, 23, 5, 32, 3],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }, {
                        label: 'Whatever 2',
                        data: [12, 1, 22, 15, 2, 23],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the esm version, you need to use the following link with the umd build: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.2.1/chart.umd.js

Comment: Thanks. That's working. I wasn't aware of the fact, that there are different functionalities in chartjs.x.y.